# Avoid and handle `File in Use` Excel Notification

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently working on a Registration System using Excel.
So I have a `.xlsm` file which users access for registration.
I have a `.xlsb` file as my database.
Both files are located in a `Network Drive` where multiple users can access.

**Here's what my macro does:**

1. Collect Info from user.
2. Open the database (`.xlsb file`) and then write info then close and save.
3. I included a routine that will check if the `.xlsb` file is open, and if so you cannot register.
4. I also included a routine that will send notification email to me if somebody made a successful registration. The email provided a link to the `.xlsb` file.

**Problem:**

This is my problem.

Above set-up works fine.
But suddenly, I cannot proceed with registration because it says that the file is in use (the `.xlsb` file).
So I checked the file in the `Network Drive` and open it manually and below appears:

[image: File in use notification]

Normally, when I encouter above, I chose `Notify` and after 5-10 secs, a read-write notification will pop-up.
This time it did not.
 I waited, and lasted 5 minutes and the read-write notification never came.

With this, the registration `.xlsm` doesn't work anymore since the system like triggered a lifetime `file-in-use` status on my `.xlsb` file.

**Questions:**

1. How do I fix this?
2. How can I avoid this from happenning.
3. Is there a way to track where the file is currently linked?

If you need to take a look at my codes, I'll provide it.
I just think that the problem does not lie there so I did not post any.
If you have any clarifications, just comment it out.

Comment: Maybe get a network admin to close it for you. I used to do that for users on a small network when files would get stuck in an "open" state like you're describing. Something to do with Network Shares if memory serves. In the long run, maybe switch to a database or SharePoint or something that's designed for multiple users at once.

Comment: @DougGlancy Yeah, that's what I did. I asked help from the NA. But of course, users cannot do this everytime. And I agree as well with the idea of DBase or SP, but I just need a temporary system which will cater this kind of transaction. Well then number of users can be categorized as small but the Network where the files are located is big. So that might be what causes the `infinite open` state. I was thinking that maybe there's a way to improve or somehow a workaround to get what I want.

Comment: I'm sure you'll learn a lot doing this :) Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround I put up is to use `ADODB` in accessing the `.xlsb` file.
 That eliminated the need to open/close the file.

I soon migrated the entire system to Access, with a properly set up front and back end database. 
 Posted this as answer for those trying to do the same thing as a pointer for a possible solution.