# Change from read-only to read-write does not trigger workbook_open in xlsm

Tags: vba, excel

When I try to open excel file which is opened by other user on server, excel offer me two options:

1) open excel file in read-only mode

2) open excel file in read-olny mode and notify me once the other user leave the excel file for writing

If I choose the second option, once the other user leave the excel file, I get message in my excel and open the excel file in read-write mode. If this excel file contains auto_open (or workbook_open) subroutine, it runs only during opening excel file, not again when changing access from read-only to read-write mode.

This is valid in case of xlsm file. In case of old xls file, the auto_open (workbook_open) works both during opening file, as well as during changing the mode from read-only to read-write.

Is there any way to trigger any other subroutine during change from read-only to read-write mode in xlsm file? If not, is there any way to block option "notify" at the warning message about read-only excel file?

[warning message same as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22214150/how-to-avoid-and-handle-file-in-use-excel-notification)

Answer (score 0):

I would have to say no you cant block the "Notify me" option, but what you could do is use a global variable and evaluate that variable in the load function to say if its false(hasnt run) then do whatever stuff, and if its true (meaning its already been run) then not to do whatever stuff

Comment: Actually I want to trigger some action at the moment when the user open my excel file for writing. Although the auto_open load function does not know if the excel file will be opened for writing later at the time the excel is started. I am afraid the global variable itself will not help me.